# Changing button styles programmatically

Tags: android, button, togglebutton

In my app the user views a document they have made. It includes various elements including **Buttons** and **ToggleButtons**.
The user can set a custom theme that changes the **Typeface** and Text color used in the TextViews/EditTexts as well as the background color of the layouts.
All these elements are generated at runtime.

What I would like is to make the Buttons/ToggleButtons respect the style the user chooses. I can determine the basic background color I want for the buttons at runtime, but if I use **View.setBackGroundColor()** it becomes a flat colored rectangle whereas I would like to retain the border/shadow effect, plus the color change when pressed. i.e. i would like it to look and behave like a Button, just shaded a different color.

Is it possible to get what I want, given that until the app is running the actual colors required remain unknown?

Answer (score 0):

Rounded corners, shadow effects, etc are often accomplished in Android by using images. See this [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) for an explanation of how that works.

A widget can have either an image background, or a solid color background. So, by setting the background color you are override the background image. If you want to change the color without losing everything else, you need to edit the image files.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can't change styles programmatically; you can set the look of a screen, or part of a layout, or individual button in your XML layout using themes or styles. Themes can, however, be applied programmatically.

There is also such a thing as a StateListDrawable which lets you define different drawables for each state the your Button can be in, whether focused, selected, pressed, disabled and so on.

For example, to get your button to change colour when it's pressed, you could define an XML file called res/drawable/my_button.xml directory like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />
<item
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal" />
```

You can then apply this selector to a Button by setting the property

```
btn.setBackground(drawable);
```